# How to make sure that $ formula $ will be on one line?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent LaTeX from breaking inline formulas globally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/how-can-i-prevent-latex-from-breaking-inline-formulas-globally)
>   [How do I keep a string of text together without it doing a line break?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48772/how-do-i-keep-a-string-of-text-together-without-it-doing-a-line-break)

So I have code like (sorry for russian):

```
Если на полуплоскость действует касательное усилие $T=P_{x} \delta (x-c)$, а нормальная нагрузка $N$ отсутствует, тогда на основании соотношений \eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq2}, получаем:
```

Which renders like:

[image]

So I wonder how to make `$T=P_{x} \delta (x-c)$` stay on some line ( one with text top or bottom )?

Comment: If you put it in an `\mbox{}` there will be no breaks int he formula. If you want it on its own line and centered thatn use display mode by surrounding it with `\[ \]`.

Comment: Please review your previous questions and: 1. Respond to any of the comments, 2. Upvote the answers that were helpful by clicking on the up arrow, and 3. Accepting the ones that were the most helpful in resolving your question.

Comment: You can try: `\relpenalty=10000\binoppenalty=10000` , see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51263/what-are-penalties-and-which-ones-are-defined

Comment: I try ` $\mbox{T=P_{x}\delta(x-c)}$` but it does not compile =(

Comment: Put curly braces around the part of the equation where you want to suppress breaks.

Comment: @user1078642: Use `\mbox{$T=P_{x}\delta(x-c)$}`, since `\mbox` reverts its contents into text mode requiring you to force math mode via `$...$` again.